# Allowing traffic to a certain path in AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

The way that AWS WAF works to be very unclear, at the moment, I'm trying to allow all traffic to a certain path.

Lets say everything to `/admin` should be allowed and not go through the `xss` or `sql` filters that I've added from the "common attacks" to my setup via their official guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-common-attacks.html

But the UI and docs makes it really unclear how to do this. Any help or resources would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# waf using rate-based rule 

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "example" {
    name        = "example"
    description = "Example of a regional rate based statement."
    scope       = "REGIONAL"

    default_action {
      allow {}
    }

    rule {
        name     = "LoginRateLimit"
        priority = 0

        action {
            count {}
        }

        visibility_config {
            cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
            metric_name                = "Metric-Limit"
            sampled_requests_enabled   = true
        }

        statement {
            rate_based_statement {
                limit              = 500
                aggregate_key_type = "IP"

                scope_down_statement {
                    byte_match_statement {
                        field_to_match {
                            uri_path {}
                        }

                        positional_constraint = "CONTAINS"
                        search_string         = "login"
                        text_transformation {
                            priority = 0
                            type     = "NONE"
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        metric_name                = "any-name"
        sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @JeremyCaney this answer had pretty readable code, I see your point, but this is the best answer, a little bit of an explainer above the code would be helpful to others however.

Comment: "Lets say everything to /admin should be allowed" The web ACL posted here doesn't seem to provide this.

Comment: @CameronHudson I think it gives a good idea on how to accomplish this. It worked for me, ill add the one I created to my question to show.

Answer (score 3):

Is `/admin` part of the URL? If so, can you write a simple string-match rule on URL to whitelist it?

FYI, rules are triggered based on order you put in so put the whitelist rules need to be at top.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and add different rules to different paths using [String Match Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-string-conditions.html).

Configure it to filter on part of the URI (URL that identifies a resource).